# Button alignment is not set properly when text of the button is removed

Tags: html, css

I have 8 buttons in my html page. On removing the text of the buttons, the alignment is not getting set properly.

here is my html page... which has two rows of 4 buttons each.. on clearing the text on the buttons programmatically, buttons are getting displaced.

Please suggest..

```
<div id="div1">
  <button class="buttonEvents" name="1" type="button" onmouseup="buttonInput(event,this)"
  oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();"></button>
  <button class="buttonEvents" name="2" type="button" onmouseup="buttonInput(event,this)"
  oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();"></button>
  <button class="buttonEvents" name="3" type="button" onmouseup="buttonInput(event,this)"
  oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();"></button>
  <button class="buttonEvents" name="4" type="button" onmouseup="buttonInput(event,this)"
  oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();"></button>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <button class="buttonEvents" name="5" type="button" onmouseup="buttonInput(event,this)"
  oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();"></button>
  <button class="buttonEvents" name="6" type="button" onmouseup="buttonInput(event,this)"
  oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();"></button>
  <button class="buttonEvents" name="7" type="button" onmouseup="buttonInput(event,this)"
  oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();"></button>
  <button class="buttonEvents" name="8" type="button" onmouseup="buttonInput(event,this)"
  oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();"></button>
</div>
```

and corresponding css is here:

```
.buttonEvents {
    background-color: #1E5184;

    border-bottom: 0.1em solid # 555;
    border-left: 0.1em solid#CCC;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-right: 0.1em solid #555; 

    border-top: 0.1em solid # CCC;
    color: #EEE;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0.2em; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    width: 185px;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: any reason for the extra lines ? other than making it very difficult to read (IMO) ! I have formatted it a little better now

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PzeU3/ - what do you mean by *displaced* and what are you expecting?

Comment: buttons are not getting aligned in a row.. more spacing is found between rows of buttons

Comment: @ZoltanToth: The problem becomes clear once text is added to some of the buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/PzeU3/2/. The OP really should have done that to make the question clearer.

Comment: here is the javascript that I'm using to change the text on the buttons.

if(events <= 4)
{
document.getElementsByName(events)[0].innerHTML="buttonName";

document.getElementsByName(events)[0].value="buttonName";

document.getElementsByName(buttonId)[0].disabled = false;

document.getElementsByName(buttonId)[0].style.backgroundColor="#1e5184";
   }
   else 
   {
    document.getElementsByName(events)[0].innerHTML="";
    document.getElementsByName(events)[0].disabled = true;
    document.getElementsByName(events)[0].style.backgroundColor = "grey";
   }

Comment: @thirtydot It was a classic screw up. On my screen the buttons appeared in 4 rows (because of the width) - 3+1+3+1 and I RANDOMLY entered some text in a button that happened to be the single on the line, so didn't see any misalignment :)

Answer (score 4):

Add `vertical-align: top` to your `button`s.

`button`s are by default inline (or `inline-block`). The default `vertical-align` value is `baseline`. Having no text in the button adjusts where the baseline is.